# Apache: permission error while opening file

Tags: apache-2.2, python, cgi

I have a cgi script that opens a file (using python).

The cgi script runs fine but when I try to open this file, I get a permission error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/asdf/pkgs/linux/intel/apache/2.2.14.rhas5.x86_64/htdocs/Sites/cgi-bin/avgsBarGraphView.py", line 304, in <module>
    main()   File "/asdf/pkgs/linux/intel/apache/2.2.14.rhas5.x86_64/htdocs/Sites/cgi-bin/avgsBarGraphView.py", line 61, in main
    f=open('/asdf/home/asdf/PYTHON/PERFRPTCRONJOB/TEST_FILES/testfile','r') PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/asdf/home/asdf/PYTHON/PERFRPTCRONJOB/TEST_FILES/testfile'
```

I've added the folder containing `/asdf/home/asdf/PYTHON/PERFRPTCRONJOB/TEST_FILES/testfile` to my httpd.conf.

```
<Directory "/asdf/home/asdf/PYTHON/PERFRPTCRONJOB/TEST_FILES/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I've also changed the permissions of the folder TEST_FILES to 777 and the permissions of testfile to 777. I can open the file via python from the command line but when I try to open this file by running a cgi-script, it fails.

Comment: Never, ever, set the permissions to any file or directory to 777. There are **no** exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check "x" permission for **every** (sub)directory in the path /asdf/home/asdf/PYTHON/PERFRPTCRONJOB/TEST_FILES/testfile

You can do this with the command:

```
ls -ld /asdf/home/asdf/PYTHON/PERFRPTCRONJOB/TEST_FILES/testfile /asdf/home/asdf/PYTHON/PERFRPTCRONJOB/TEST_FILES /asdf/home/asdf/PYTHON/PERFRPTCRONJOB /asdf/home/asdf/PYTHON /asdf/home/asdf /asdf/home /asdf
```

Comment: It's 777 starting with PERFRPTCRONJOB. I did chmod 777 PERFRPTCRONJOB -R

Comment: I've edited my answer. There is an instruction to check **all** directories in the path, not just some of them

Comment: Does that matter? I don't want extra permissions for parent directories of PERFRPTCRONJOB.

Comment: Every directory in the path should be "executable". Otherwise the file won't open. If you cannot fulfill this requirement, change your directory structure. There is nothing more I can help you: Only you can know which permissions are allowable for which directories

Comment: Oh, one more correction: `ls -l` should be changed to `ls -ld` (I've edited the answer.)

Comment: Please don't EVER EVER EVER set 777 permissions.  It is absolutely never the correct answer.